# Putting Around aspect around lombok generated toString method is not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop, lombok

I have a springboot app build with Gradle, with lombok and lombok's toString method doesn't filter null values, so I thought of putting a aspect around toString and customize the message.

I assumed lombok code gen at compile time, and aspect doing at runtime might be able to attach it there, but it didn't work. So wondering if anyone able to do aspect around lombok generated code.

I used @Data lombok annotation on the classes.

```java
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@Aspect
@Component
public class ToStringAdvice {
  @Around(
      "execution(public String com.example..*.toString())")
  public Object toString(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("before");
    return pjp.proceed();
  }
}
```

```java
@Data
public class Dto{
 private String field1;
 private String field2;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn what an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is and then edit your question to provide one. For example, where is your lomboked class? How do you build the project (IDE, Maven, Gradle, ...)? Et cetera.